# Differences between Jython and Python

Tags: python, syntax, jython

I know Jython converts Python code into Java byte code, but are there any syntax changes between the two? and as a side question is Jython 3.x usable yet or is it still being ported?

Comment: [Read the website](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo#Is_Jython_the_same_language_as_Python.3F).

Comment: Syntax changes? Not any intentional ones. Jython has recently released the alpha version of 2.7. It's likely it will be a while before a 3.x version will be released.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jython is an [implementation](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/LangSyntax.html#the-difference-between-jython-and-python) of the Python language.  It is not a different language at all.

According to the [Jython website](http://www.jython.org/), the latest stable version is currently 2.5.3b1, and the latest development version is 2.7a2.  As far as I know, no one is currently working on an 3.x-compatible version of Jython.

Answer (score 17):

In a nutshell

### Differences of - Python & Jython

#### Python

1. C
2. Multi-platform
3. Compiles to .pyc
4. Extend with C
5. GIL 1*
6. Python Garbage Collection

1*. Global Interpreter Lock, explained in [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) Python documentation, chapter 8.1 (1)

#### Jython

1. 100% Java
2. Any JVM (currently 1.1+)
3. Compiles to .class
4. Extend with Java
5. Truly multi-threaded
6. Java garbage collection

For more information there is nothing better than visiting there on [website](http://wiki.python.org/)

Comment: Question was for syntax differences.

Answer (score 6):

There are 3 major implementations available for Python language. Jython is a java implementation, Cython is C implementation and IronPython is c# implementation. As far as Python language syntax is concerned, it remains consistent in all implementations. Regarding the last part of your question, I dont think Jython version 3.x is released or in use yet, probably you meant python 3.x - if so, yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these websites:

1) [Differences between CPython and Jython](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/differences.html)

2) [Jython FAQ](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo#Is_Jython_the_same_language_as_Python.3F)